# Should fewer or less be used when specific quantities are given?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I know that fewer is used for countable nouns and less is used for uncountable nouns, but when a specific quantity is given, should I use fewer or less. For example would it be correct to say 'there are fewer than 5 apples' or 'there are less than 5 apples'?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not a quantity is specified doesn't matter: if the noun can be counted in the sense in which it is used in your sentence, then, conventionally, *fewer* should be used. Note that *less* is also used by many speakers informally or colloquially.